# Is there any resource that provides a list of the most used/common components of the different statements (e.g. balance sheet) of an annual report?

Tags: accounting, balance-sheet, financial-statements, annual-report, income-statement

I am looking for a resource that provides a list of a "perfect":

1. statement of financial position (balance sheet)
2. statement of earnings
3. statement of cash flow

containing components (e.g. for the balance sheet: cash and cash equivalents,...) that are most used comparing all US-GAAP 10-k (annual report). So to say a statement of financial position/earnings/cash flow that covers most of the components of all existing 10-k of different companies (most representable)?

If yes, I would be pleased to know this source. Thank's in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

These Investopedia articles cover many of the most common items:

[Balance Sheet](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/balancesheet.asp)

[Cash Flow](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cashflowstatement.asp)

[Income Statement](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/plstatement.asp)